# Describing a general vector curve

Tags: functions

Given a vector-valued function $\vec{g}: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R^3}$ described as $\vec{g}(t) = \vec{a}+(\sin(t))\vec{b}$, where $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are constant, if one wants to describe the curve $\vec{x}=\vec{g}(t)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and give a sketch, as well as a physical interpretation, will it be correct to say that we're dealing with a periodic motion of a particle, which can be described as simple harmonic?

I believe there is no general sketch of such a function.

Comment: A bit unclear what you're asking.....

Comment: I have an exercise question where it's asked to give a sketch of $\vec{g}(t) = \vec{a}+(\sin(t))\vec{b}$, as well as to physically interpret the motion of the particle.

Comment: There is a general sketch.  $\vec g(t)$ describes a point moving along a line segment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by your comment:

$g(t)=a+\sin(t)b$

As you suspected this is simply harmonic motion (in the direction of $b$ about $a$)

The period is $2\pi$ "time units"

The magnitude is $\|b\|$

Just as you'd expect.

You got the question right!